# Drools: how to retrieve the fact in response from Kie Execution Server?

Tags: java, server, drools, rule-engine, kie

I am using Kie Execution Server 6.2 final and I have a simple rule file deployed on the server and I am accessing it through rest api. When I try to execute the rules, everything goes well, but I do not get newly inserted fact in the response.

Here is my drl file

```
rule "Odd Rule"
dialect "mvel" 
when
    testRecord : TestRecord((integerValue & 1) == 1 && integerValue != 0  , testId: testRecordId , intValue :integerValue )
then
    System.out.println( "Odd Rule- Test ID "+ testId );
    TestResult $testResult = new TestResult();
    $testResult.setTestrecordId(testId);
    $testResult.setDescription("Odd Rule");
    $testResult.setValueInteger(intValue * (-10));
    insert($testResult);

   end
```

and post request on server

```
 <batch-execution>
 <insert out-identifier="TestReord">
 <com.drools.poc.TestRecord>
 <integerValue>10</integerValue>
 <testRecordId>10</testRecordId>
 </com.drools.poc.TestRecord>
 </insert>
```

response from server

```
<response type="SUCCESS" msg="Container Container1 successfully called.">
    <results><execution-results>
    <result identifier="TestReord">
    <com.drools.poc.TestRecord>
    <integerValue>10</integerValue>
    <testRecordId>10</testRecordId>
    </com.drools.poc.TestRecord>
    </result>
    <fact-handle identifier="TestReord" external form="0:29:1697585638:1697585638:29:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT"/>
    </execution-results></results>
</response>
```

Comment: You need to use another command such as getObjects to retrieve inserted facts. Or modify the inserted fact itself.

Comment: So how does your client create the batch-execution command with the insert command? It should be possible to add the getObjects command the same way.

Comment: @launeThank you so much. I did the same